# How to access the iframe element selector?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have an HTML page which has a child HTML which gets generated dynamically. I want to change the styles of few child HTML elements,but I'm not able to access any of the child HTML elements

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="new.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<body>
 <iframe id="cartoonVideo" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/ABCDEFGH" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>

**Child html gets generated here** 

#document
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<head>
link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="new.css">
</head>
<body>
<div class="access"></div>
</body>
</html>


</body>
</html>
```

How do I access the child HTML div which has class as access. Either through CSS or any JavaScript or JQuery methods?

Comment: please let us know your goals to do that . like if you want to autoplay this video content than there will be an alternate solution , but if you want to change the content  inside this you will have to see **corx orign** problem , it would be tricky.

Comment: Probable duplicate - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/217776/how-to-apply-css-to-iframe

Answer (score 0):

use function contents() this returns the html contents inside your iframe

```
$("#cartoonVideo").contents().find('.access')
```